# How do I get IntelliJ's Project Files view to show the packages and directories in the source folders?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, ide, resource-files

I can't seem to figure out how to get IntelliJ to show the directories under `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`. I've tried to delete my `.idea` file and reimport the project but that did not help. If you notice in the first image below, there is no arrow next to these source folders. The second image is what my source folders look like when I go to `File > Project Structure > Modules.` I see all of the directories/packages in the second picture, but I want to be able to navigate to them in the Project Files section.

How do I correct this?

[image][image]

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is minimal, as complete as I can give, and verifiable as far as me putting in pictures. What else would you like me to include to make this easier to answer?

Comment: Zip and share the project so that others can open it and reproduce the issue.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to share the project. I'll try to think of another way to be more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, just in case anyone else runs into this problem.

FYI, I'm on a Mac.

Go to File > Project Structure.

[image]

Make sure you are under the "Modules" section (under Project Settings on the left).

Select/Single-click the module that is giving you issues.

Click the minus sign above the module to delete the module (this will not delete the module from disk).

[image]

After deleting the module, add the project/module back again by going to the same place as before, but clicking the plus sign instead of the minus.

[image]

I think my particular issue is when I originally added my project and modules, I selected a specific Maven profile and for some reason IntelliJ wasn't allowing me to see my sub-directories under my source files in my project files view.